# My laptop makes a sound when it's connected to the charger and the battery is full

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

I have noticed that when my laptop is plugged-in and the battery is full, (Sometimes i leave it charging though i'm not using it) it makes a weird sound . This sound isn't loud at all but i'm wondering whether it indicates that i have a problem in my laptop or not (or smth like that).

Comment: In my opinion probably not. The computers have circuits that manage where the power from the charger goes and what circuits are energized. That can easily lead to different parts of the transformer in the charger vibrating at slightly different frequencies and producing different sound as the load on the components i the charger changes. You might even notice this with your phone charger if you listen closely enough with the phone connected and disconnected

Comment: Ooh you're talking about the notebook making a different sound. Same answer then, different circuit is energized when the battery is full and that circuit is probably making that noise. I'd still wait for proper answer though, as I'm not an electrical engineer or electrician.

Comment: Yes i've noticed that with the phone also.. Thank you!